# Как проверить вхождение строки в значения словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть словарь

```
data = {
    'Центр': ['москва', 'тверь', 'ярославль'],
    'Черноземье': ['воронеж', 'белгород', 'курск'],
    'Урал': ['челябинск', 'магнитогорск', 'екатеринбург']
}
```

Дана строка:

```
string = "москва"
```

Нужно в цикле проверить входит ли строка в значения словаря. Если да, то вернуть ключ. Т.е в данном примере должен вернуться ключ "Центр".
Думал над таким вариантом:

```
[k for k,v in data.items() if v in string])
```

но не думаю, что так правильно `in string`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать (dict compehension, цикл).

Comment: `if string in v`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def f(data, string):
    for key, value in data.items():
        if string in value:
            return key
```

```
def f(data, string):
    return [key for key, value in data.items() if string in value]
```

так будет возвращать первое значение либо `None`

```
def f(data, string):
    return ([key for key, value in data.items() if string in value] + [None])[0]
```

Comment: Тогда уж и в виде `list comprehension` надо бы тоже вариант написать, как автор вопроса изначально просил :)